# How fix No such payment_method error with stripe-php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I use `stripe/stripe-ph": "^7.2"` in my `laravel 5.8` app in 2 places with testing keys:

1. Express payments and that works ok
2. I started making
       subscription in other page with similar code and making subscription
       I got error :

> No such payment_method: tok_1FRCLkI5xQuRgDRPpX22Y64B.

Searching in net I found possible reason of this error that invalid keys are used, but checking it I see valid keys 
and I wonder how 1 page works ok, second fails, but they seems identical :

VALID page with express payment has code:

```
<div class="row row_content_centered p-3 m-3" style="justify-self: flex-start;">
    <form action="http://local-votes.com/stripe_express_payment_callback" method="GET">
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
                class="stripe-button active"
                data-key="pk_test_NNNNNNNN"
                data-amount="260"
                data-name="Select &amp; Vote"
                data-description=" selected 2 services"
                data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-currency="usd"
        >
        </script>
        <button type="submit" class="stripe-button-el" style="visibility: visible;"><span style="display: block; min-height: 30px;">Pay with Card</span>
        </button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" onclick="javascript:document.location='http://local-votes.com/home'" style="margin-right:50px;"><span
            class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></span> &nbsp;Cancel
    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
```

Invalid page with subscription has code :

```
<form action="/subscribe_process" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="mjnmminrSADnv2Rpl5jTzPzyGl9mcqvMQGBlrLfy">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
            class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_NNNNNNNN"
            data-amount="987"
            data-name="Select &amp; Vote"
            data-description="Online course about integrating Stripe"
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-currency="usd">
    </script>
```

My private key is not `tok_1FRCLkI5xQuRgDRPpX22Y64B` as in error.
Any hints? If there is a way of debugging the errors ?

Thanks!

Comment: This type of error is usually caused by accidentally using API keys from a different account. Try to check with Postman.  This way you can make sure that you're using correct keys.

Comment: Try to check with Postman.  This way you can make sure that you're using correct keys.  https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens/tok_1FRCLkI5xQuRgDRPpX22Y64B. Also pass with headers:   Authorization:Bearer sk_test_XXXXXXX
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I think you're experiencing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501889/trouble-setting-up-a-subscription-with-laravel-5-8-cashier-stripe

Answer (score 0):

I was using stripe connect and was creating a payment profile on the connect account. Then while retrieving I wasn't passing the stripe account correctly. Once I did, the payment method was retrieved correctly. Here is the code I used. Might help someone

```html
//retrieve account
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient({platform api key});
    $payment_method = $stripe->paymentMethods->retrieve(
      {payment method id from payment_intent},
      [],
      ['stripe_account' => {stripe connect account id}]
    );
```