# Laravel Cashier 10 - Errors trying to show a Stripe element

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using this tutorial to integrate Stripe into my Laravel site using Cashier:
https://appdividend.com/2018/12/05/laravel-stripe-payment-gateway-integration-tutorial-with-example/

This tutorial was written for Cashier 9, so it does not work out of the box with Cashier 10. However, it does work making the adjustments in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812759/2002457

Except, it only works for existing Stripe customers. When I register a brand new user and try to view a plan, it gives this error: `User is not a Stripe customer. See the createAsStripeCustomer method.`

So, I try to do just that:

```php
public function show(Plan $plan, Request $request)
    {
        if($request->user()->stripe_id === null)
        {
            $request->user()->createAsStripeCustomer();
        }
        $paymentMethods = $request->user()->paymentMethods();

        $intent = $request->user()->createSetupIntent();
        return view('plans.show', compact('plan', 'intent'));
    }
```

Which yields this error: `No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe::setApiKey(<API-KEY>)". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.`

This SO answer addresses this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34508056/2002457

But the solution only works in Cashier 9, because Billable changed, so it's not clear how to set the API key.

What am I doing wrong here to create a new customer if they're not a Stripe customer already?

EDIT
- I am using the default cashier config, and I've confirmed it is pointing at the .env vars.

- I put in a `dd(config('cashier.key'));` to confirm that config is working
- I removed the old services.php config parts
- The env vars are set correctly

Here's the show method:

```php
    public function show(Plan $plan, Request $request)
    {
        $paymentMethods = $request->user()->paymentMethods();

        $intent = $request->user()->createSetupIntent();
        return view('plans.show', compact('plan', 'intent'));
    }
```

And here's the error now: `User is not a Stripe customer. See the createAsStripeCustomer method.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cashier 10 introduced some changes to the configuration including setting up the `cashier.php` configuration file. The [upgrade guide](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) details how, this [pull request commit](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/690/commits/b0cd0ec8806ac110ab02d5841caaac59bc1a3cae) shows the file.

Few things to debug this:

- make sure you've setup the config for cashier 10 correctly.
- make sure that the config key `cashier.key` is available (e.g. `ddd(config('cashier.key'));`
- double check that that your .env var's are setup correctly for stripe's API key

Comment: Your updated question is a very different problem (likely model/schema + needing to invoke `->createAsStripeCustomer()` than the question you initially asked.